# Sending A POST or GET request to php script using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Here is what needs to be done.

I have an html code and when use clicks into input field the javascript function is called.

The javascript function should call php file track.php which then counts the clicks.

Is it possible to run a php script from javascript?

Comment: What you seek my friend, ajax is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 7):

Try using the [jQuery framework](http://www.jquery.com) for your javascript code. And have a look at the [ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "track.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(){
            // code
        },
        error: function(){
            // code
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible : you'll want to search for the "[**Ajax**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)" keyword.

Ajax will allow you to send requests, from Javascript to your server, in the background -- without reloading the page.

If you just want to send a simple request, working with the `XmlHttpRequest` object that's provided by the browser is quite easy.

Else, if you want more advanced stuff, you'll probably want to take a look at Javascript libraries, such as [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Now would be as good a time as any to learn [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)